# Manually hiding the launch image not working on physical device

Tags: javascript, ios6, trigger.io

When I run my trigger.io app in the Android simulator or my Nexus phone the launch image is manually (via code) hidden correctly.  When I run the app using the iOS simulator the launch image gets hidden.  However, when I debug directly to my iOS device or package (then copy via iTunes) a dev .ipa file... and launch the app... it just hangs at the launch image.  It never goes away.  And nothing is ever logged out to the console (or the forge-error.log).

My config.json file looks like this:

```
    "launchimage": {
        "ipad": "launch/768x1004.png", 
        "android-landscape": "launch/1024x748.png", 
        "iphone-retina": "launch/640x960.png", 
        "iphone-retina4": "launch/640x1136.png",
        "iphone": "launch/320x480.png", 
        "android": "launch/640x960.png", 
        "ipad-landscape": "launch/1024x748.png",
        "ipad-retina": "launch/1536x2008.png",
    "ipad-landscape-retina": "launch/2048x1496.png",
        "hide-manually": true,
        "background-color": "#A6A6A6"
    }
```

And here is how I am hiding the launch image based on the latest [docs](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/launchimage.html)-

```
    forge.launchimage.hide(function(content) {
        // Success.
        alert("do the happy dance, it works");
    }, function(err) {
        // Error.
        alert("error");
    });
```

Please advise.  And is anyone else having an issue?  My device is running iOS 6.0.1.  Thanks for reading.

Definitely related to this question - [trigger.io hangs on splash screen in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593928/trigger-io-hangs-on-splash-screen-in-ios?rq=1)

Update: My device is a 3GS.  Any idea on how to debug this?

Comment: which version of the Forge API are you using?

Comment: @PatrickRudolph - "platform_version": "v1.4"

Comment: I've not recreated this on any of our iDevices - it could be a JS problem: if your code is erroring out before forge.launchimage.hide is called, you'd see these symptoms. How about trying with a really minimal app which just hides the launch image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v1.4.36 release notes - http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html addresses this issue (and is fixed).

> re-installing iOS IPAs on top of existing installations caused hangs on launchimage in some situations